# Actionbar Custom Position

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new with Android development, and I received a layout for an app where I have to put some kind of bar with images above the action bar.

I searched a lot in Google but I couldn't find anything about change the action bar position. I also found some info saying:

> Google highly recommend to NOT change the action bar position(...)

Well, how I got some custom views for the action bar icons was to put the view below the action bar.  However, what I am supposed to do is put the view above the action bar.
Is there a way to put a view above the action bar or change the action bar position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to put a view above the action bar or change the action bar position?

Not that I am aware of.